# How to programmatically pass the name of the font with which the SymbolInsert function should open?

Tags: excel, vba, winapi

I can programmatically call the built-in function SymbolInsert in VBA Excel in three ways known to me:

```
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "SymbolInsert"
or
Application.CommandBars.FindControl(ID:=308)
or
Application.Dialogs(771).Show
```

How to programmatically pass the name of the font with which the SymbolInsert function should be open?

Unfortunately I haven't found a solution yet

Comment: Do you know the ascii code/unicode of the symbol you want to insert?

Comment: Unfortunately, i do not know. Characters will be selected by the user

Comment: And from what do you know the font that should be passed?

Comment: I need to set the default font